# What is the process of making vivre card?

Tags: one-piece

From One Piece wikia for [Vivre card](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vivre_Card)

> Vivre Cards, also known as the "paper of life" (命の紙 Inochi no Kami), are a special form of paper made in the New World. A Vivre Card is made from part of a person’s fingernail which is then made into paper.

[image: sabo with Luffy's vivre card]

Sabo made one. He made it himself or gave someone to make it.

I want to know the process of converting finger nail into paper.How they do it? And is it made only in new world also?

Answer (score 5):

The only explanation we have on Vivre Card so far is from chapter 489, when Lola explained it to Nami. At that time, Lola was pretty vague, but that's the only thing we know so far. We are about to meet Vegapunk in a few days (a few years in real life probably), so we might know more when Smoker and Tashigi reach him.

### How are they made?

Lola explained that there are indeed **specialized shops** that make those cards and that the process to make such cards is just to **put the owner's fingernail in a mix and create a special sheet of paper with them**, but she did not specify the mix that is needed or the way to transform the mix into the actual sheet of paper.

### Are they only made in the New World?

The translation I have used in the below screenshot says that

> Bibli Cards only work in the New World,

which we know to be false, since the Strawhats used Rayleigh's Vivre Card on the Grand Line. I have found a different translation that says that

> Vivre Cards are only available in the New World.

So to me that sounds like **only the New World has specialized shops to create such cards, but if you know the process to making them, you could make them anywhere.**

[image]

Comment: Is it made only in new world and sabo said , he made one , is he implying that he made it himself

Comment: lots of question are depending on Vegapunk, but few days in OP universe, here i don't know how long will it take

Comment: @mirroroftruth Yes, Sabo (or another Revolutionary) made it there in Dressrosa. They had to, because they only met Luffy recently and they needed his fingernail to make it.

Comment: as you say that ,it means , it can be made outside of new world also

Comment: @mirroroftruth I suppose they can, but there is no proof of that yet. Rayleigh could have gotten his card from several years ago when he was still in the New World and Sabo is now in the New World as well. So I suppose they need an ingredient which you can only find in the New World and it would be expensive/difficult to export, but I suppose you could take the ingredients outside of the New World, there just isn't any proof of that.